# Reducer Composition - why do we need to re assign todos with Object.assign() why not just call the other reducer?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, redux, react-redux

In the case of this reducer composition example, why can't we just return the reducer we are calling? Meaning, in the `todoApp` reducer in the case of either `ADD_TODO` or `TOGGLE_TODO` we are using the other reducer: `todos`. I understand that. But I don't understand why we can't just set the case in `todoApp` as

```
function todoApp(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
    case TOGGLE_TODO:
      return todos(state.todos, action)
```

vs what we have here:

```
function todoApp(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
    case TOGGLE_TODO:
       return Object.assign({}, state, {
         todos: todos(state.todos, action)
       })
```

Especially since the todos reducer is returning the full new state object, right? Aren't we still following redux rules and not modifying the state by returning the result of the second reducer?

```
function todos(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          text: action.text,
          completed: false
        }
      ]
    case TOGGLE_TODO:
      return state.map((todo, index) => {
        if (index === action.index) {
          return Object.assign({}, todo, {
            completed: !todo.completed
          })
        }
        return todo
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}

function todoApp(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        visibilityFilter: action.filter
      })
    case ADD_TODO:
    case TOGGLE_TODO:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        todos: todos(state.todos, action)
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking why this

```
case TOGGLE_TODO:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    todos: todos(state.todos, action)
  })
```

... can't just be this ...

```
case TOGGLE_TODO:
  return todos(state.todos, action)
```

You have to be mindful of the *shape* of the state in the specific context of the reducer you're working with

- `todo` has a state shape of `[Todo]` – where `[Todo]` is an *Array* of todos
- `todoApp` has a state shape of `{todos: [Todo]}`

If you were to use your suggested code

```
case TOGGLE_TODO:
  return todos(state.todos, action)
```

Knowing that `todos` will return `[Todo]`, you would be replacing your `todoApp` state ...

```
{todos: [Todo]}
```

... with

```
[Todo]
```

... which is not the correct shape.

---

> So if the shape were the same this would be ok, I wouldn't be modifying the state otherwise, correct? – Anna Garcia 25 mins ago

Correct, but the reason they're using `Object.assign` in this case is a forward-thinking best practice.

You could just do

```
case TOGGLE_TODO:
  return {todos: todos(state.todos, action)}
```

But, it's reasonable to think that your app will have other "slices" of state that it needs to care about – not *just* `todos`. In such a case, the `TOGGLE_TODO` action only acts upon the `todos` slice. It's being mindful to update `todos` in a way that doesn't clobber all of the other existing properties in this context.

So let's say our app had two other slices of state, `foo`, and `bar`. If we do ...

```
// where state = {foo: 1, bar: 2, todos: [ ... ]}
case TOGGLE_TODO:
  return {todos: todos(state.todos, action)}
```

then we're only returning the `{todos: ...}` – the `foo` and `bar` properties/values have been dropped! Not good!

Instead, we must be careful to preserve other state entries and *only* operate on the state we intend to modify

```
// where state = {foo: 1, bar: 2, todos: [ ... ]}
case TOGGLE_TODO:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {todos: todos(state.todos, action)})
```

Now we will get back

```
{foo: 1, bar: 2, todos: newTodosArray}
```

which is exactly what we want – all `foo`, `bar`, and `todos` properties are still in the `todoApp` state.

---

**Object spread syntax**

There is a proposal to support spread syntax for objects, which could simplify the `Object.assign` example to

```
case TOGGLE_TODO:
  return {...state, todos: todos(state.todos, action)}
```

But until that makes it into ECMAScript, you'll have to babelify it using [transform-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)

Comment: So if the shape were the same this would be ok, I wouldn't be modifying the state otherwise, correct?

Comment: @AnnaGarcia updated my answer to address your question

Answer (score 0):

The main concept of redux is that you can never directly modify state, you must return a new state. Your proposed solution would be modifying the current state, which isn't allowed.

> Especially since the todos reducer is returning the full new state
>   object, right?1

They key word here is 'new'. It must be a new state object, not a modification of the current one.

Comment: But isn't it returning a new state and not modifying it if we let the second reducer take over here? How would it be modifying otherwise?